# Define a map of map type in C++?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am trying to define a unordered map from `long` to a `map` from `long` to `FILE *`, but keep getting compiler error. Any idea how to correct it?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<unordered_map>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long ulong;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned char uchar;

typedef std::unordered_map<long, std::unordered_map<long, *FILE> > TYPE1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    TYPE1 x;
    x[1][2] = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the compiler error

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 te2a.cc
te2a.cc:15:64: error: template argument 2 is invalid
te2a.cc:15:64: error: template argument 5 is invalid
te2a.cc:15:66: error: template argument 2 is invalid
te2a.cc:15:66: error: template argument 5 is invalid
te2a.cc:15:73: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
te2a.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
te2a.cc:19:5: error: invalid types ‘TYPE1 {aka int}[int]’ for array subscript
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the placing of the asterisk:

`typedef std::unordered_map<long, std::unordered_map<long, FILE*>> TYPE1;`

will do it.

Comment: Thanks @r2-dequeue, that's it!  Will accept your answer in a few minutes when SO allows.

Comment: @codingFun In addition to this, you want to change `x[1][2]` to `x[0][1]` I think.

Answer (score 1):

Note the asterisk:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<long, std::unordered_map<long, *FILE>> TYPE1;
```

change it to:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<long, std::unordered_map<long, FILE*>> TYPE1;
```

Comment: Thanks @tryinhard.  Your answer is right. Wish I can accept it too.